# How to organize overlapping javascript onclick events in overlapping divs

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, handler, overlapping

Especially on smaller screens like iPad and iPhone it happens that a click on a element does not only trigger the "onclick function of the actual script but also the "onclick" function of the javascript of the underlaying div.

On my homepage http://www.somersetsights.co.za/en/index.html for example on a iPad a click on the like button activates the FB Like dialog and a click on the OK button of this Like dialog triggers the start of a movie from the slideshow function underneeth the Like dialog.

I tried to find a solution by googling this problem but struggled to find something. I am not a beginner but I am also not a experianced javascript programmer. Help would be very much appreciated.

Peter

Comment: This is what is known as event bubbling. One solution is to attach 1 event handler on the top level Dom event and within that function switch the action for that event based on the rules of your design - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: Look at `e.target` where `e` is the _Event_.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that could help you : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html
Tell us if you use jQuery or another JS library.

Comment: I realize just now what means 'underlaying'... sorry